# How does one install a specific ocaml compiler when it doesn't appear on the opam switch list?

Tags: ocaml, opam

I've installed this compiler before in a docker container, but I don't understand why it's missing right now. Command and error:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ opam switch create ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1 ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda
[ERROR] No compiler matching `ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda' found, use `opam switch list-available' to see what is available, or use `--packages' to
        select packages explicitly.
```

but it's not in the list:

```
(iit_synthesis) brando9~ $ opam switch list-available
# Listing available compilers from repositories: default
# Name                  # Version # Synopsis
ocaml-option-32bit      1         Set OCaml to be compiled in 32-bit mode for 64-bit Linux and OS X hosts
ocaml-option-flambda    1         Set OCaml to be compiled with flambda activated
ocaml-option-nnpchecker 1         Set OCaml to be compiled with --enable-naked-pointers-checker
ocaml-option-spacetime  1         Set OCaml to be compiled with spacetime activated
ocaml-options-vanilla   1         Ensure that OCaml is compiled with no special options enabled
```

---

## Opam update fails

Output:

```
$ opam update --all

<><> Updating package repositories ><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
Processing  1/1: [default: http]


Processing  1/1: [default: http]

[default] synchronised from https://opam.ocaml.org
[ERROR] Could not update repository "default": "~/anaconda/bin/patch -p1 -i /dfs/scratch0/brando9/.opam/log/patch-99014-0624b6" exited with code 2
```

---

I probably should have started with this but I installed opam with "manually" with deb because I don't have sudo. In particular I did this:

```
# - opam (snap, no sudo)
# ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access
apt-get download opam
#apt-get download opam_1.2.2-4_amd64
# manually checked the opam name
#ls | less 
mkdir -p ~/.local
dpkg -x opam_1.2.2-4_amd64.deb ~/.local/bin
export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc.user
source ~/.bashrc.user

tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"

opam --version
```

before that I did try installing opam with conda (which has worked in the past) but it failed. I wonder if that screwed things up :/. Will try to reproduce to post the conda error. But I ran `conda install -c conda-forge opam`.

---

related:

- [How to install a specific version of ocaml compiler with opam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40898292/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-ocaml-compiler-with-opam)
- https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/why-doesnt-my-server-show-the-ocaml-compiler-that-i-need/10917
- https://www.reddit.com/r/ocaml/comments/zed88p/how_does_one_install_a_specific_ocaml_compiler/
- [How does one install opam without sudo priveledges on linux/ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708063/how-does-one-install-opam-without-sudo-priveledges-on-linux-ubuntu)

Comment: This is obvious so you've probably tried it. But... make sure you have the latest list of packages with `opam update`.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I tried `opam update --all` but it failed. I don't understand what anaconda has anything to do with opam but that made it fail. I will try your simpler version. Due to it being on a distributed filesystem it might take me a while to update util it succeeds or fails.

Comment: Which version of opam do you have, and how did you install it?

Comment: In particular, the call to anaconda in the error message of `opam update` is suspicious.

Comment: @octachron I update the question. I did try to install opam with conda since it's worked in the past but then I moved to manually install it with apt-get. Note my install way is not standard since I don't have sudo priviledges in the HPC servers I'm using.

Comment: @glennsl I added the details in the question for the install. I installed in a none standard way since I don't have sudo.

Comment: ok since the installation might be the source of the issue I will try that again & made a new question to seperate the two: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708063/how-does-one-install-opam-without-sudo-priveledges-on-linux-ubuntu